# Ruby what does this line of code mean?

Tags: ruby

```
def load_­comics(pat­h)
    comics={}
    File.forea­ch(path) do |line­|
        name, url = line.­split(': ')
        comics[nam­e] = url.s­trip
    end
    comics  #<<< THIS LINE
end
```

I'm used to PHP, what does `comics` do? I'm a bit confused (I'm doing the tutorials on tryruby.org and it didn't explain that section).

Comment: Off-topic, but `Hash[File.readlines(path).map { |line| line.strip.split(": ") }]` will do this without the need for temporary variable assignment.

Comment: The code I used is actually from the tutorial there, to make it as easy to understand as possible I suppose hence the need for temporary variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its the return value of the method.

Comment: Ahhh I see, no need for return comics

Comment: The point or returning the comics at the end of the method is so that you can chain methods; e.g. `load_comics("/some/path").each do { |comic| /* do something with each comic */ }`

Answer (score 1):

comics is hash, probably the result will look like this:

```
comics = { 'name1' => 'url1', 'name2' => 'url2', ...}
```